# Ubuntu iso-file version verification not working

Tags: configuration, usb-drive, iso

Am following the instructions to create a bootable ubuntu usb drive.

(https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu?_ga=2.116597062.1969503665.1501628494-1805752603.1501628494#2)

The verification part isn't going well, typed in the command, in the terminal,

$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374 2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092" "C598 6B4F 1257 FFA8 6632 CBA7 4618 1433 FBB7 5451"

There was a typo, so this command was entered a second time without the typo.

```
gpg --list-keys --with-fingerprint 0xFBB75451 0xEFE21092
```

finds the correct keys, now. But

```
cat /home/ubuntu/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

says, "no such file". How can the verification process be corrected and placed back on track?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like doing a manual check worked, using terminal command

```
sha256sum ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```

The hash matched.